# C# System.Net trace log - only trace one method and ignore others?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, trace, system.diagnostics, system.net

I'm using System.Net tracing as described here:

http://ferozedaud.blogspot.com/2009/08/tracing-with-systemnet.html

But that traces every request made with HttpWebRequest.  The trace file is huge.  I only want to trace what happens when I am calling a certain URI eg:

```
https://api.example.com/oauth/RequestToken
```

Because connecting to this URI has problems after my web app has been running for several hours.

I want to ignore all requests to other URIs eg:

```
https://api.example.com/Foo
```

Because these requests are working fine, and are filling up the log with data that I do not need.

Comment: Are you using the svcTraceViewer tool to view the traces?  It makes it much easier to wade through data rather than viewing the .xml trace output directly.

Comment: No I'm using TextWriterTraceListener to write to a text file.  The problem is not just the huge amount of data, but the huge file size.  So I would prefer to somehow stop it from writing everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [Message Filters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) (scroll down about half-way down the page to the section called "Message Filters".)  Another page [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967569%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) dedicated solely to message logging filters.  Here's an educated guess at what the configuration should look like for your example:

```
<messageLogging logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" >
   <filters>
        <add xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
                xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
            /soap:Envelope/soap:Header/a:Action[starts-with(text(),'https://api.example.com/oauth/RequestToken')]
        </add>
   </filters>
</messageLogging>
```

There is also a custom implementation of a trace log filter [here](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/04/custom-trace-filter-for-a-wcf-service/) that might be helpful.